# How to use fancybox with wordpress without a plugin?

Tags: wordpress, youtube, overlay, fancybox

I am trying to use fancybox to display a youtube video within my wordpress site. I am sure of following the tutorial from fancybox.net, but I am not getting any good result. the link still opening the full page of the video in youtube instead of a fancybox overlay.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
nb: I don't wanna use a plugin

Answer (score 1):

You have to **include the fancybox css and javascripts in the site head simply** and then you can apply to any of your blog posts, content the required class or id.

Comment: I included the css and javascript, but nothing happen. Is there a specific way of doing it? what file should I include from your point @Haso Keric Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through it for you and have put a working example online [HERE](http://project.wecreatepixels.com/fancybox-youtube/). Here is the js used

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".video").click(function() {
        $.fancybox({
            'padding'       : 0,
            'autoScale'     : false,
            'transitionIn'  : 'none',
            'transitionOut' : 'none',
            'title'         : this.title,
            'width'         : 640,
            'height'        : 385,
            'href'          : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
            'type'          : 'swf',
            'swf'           : {
            'wmode'             : 'transparent',
            'allowfullscreen'   : 'true'
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Hope this helps you a bit more.

Comment: Please replace the $ with jQuery instead, works better in no-conflict mode. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers

Comment: Thank you very much. I found out my problem was the reference to the child theme.